# How do I use mscapi.RSAPrivateKey for JWT signing?

Tags: java, jwt, digital-signature, mscapi, jjwt

I'm not sure how to ask this but I'm trying to use various Json Web Token implementations from the web (whether is java-jwt or jjwt etc), they all takes in a `RSAPrivateKey` as part of their signing process.

However the problem I have is that, apparently the `mscapi.RSAPrivateKey` doesn't provide the same API as the `java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey` and when I try to write my wrapper class for it, I have no idea on how to write the `getEncoded` or the `getFormat` (I'm guessing I should return "RS256" or something similar) function.

1. How can I wrap the `mscapi.RSAPrivateKey`?
2. What is the correct way to convert `mscapi.RSAPrivateKey` to the `java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not needed to get the content or wrap the private key to sign a JWT. The cryptographic provider, in your case mscapi, intentionally hides the content to protect it from extraction, or because it is physically unavailable, for example, using a smartcard. But mscapi allows to use that key for signing or encryption, so there is no reason why your library can not sign the jwt with an instance of `PrivateKey` (not RSAPrivate Key)

The issue you describe is similar to[this](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/160). It seems jjwt tries to cast the PrivateKey and the mscapi wrapper does not implement the usual interface.

I do not think you could create a wrapper on a mscapi key if getEncoded is needed, because as I said, you have not access to the keying material. So I suggest to use jjwt to build the  token (header.payload) and  sign it yourself using the standard signature api

Comment: That's the weird thing, I use `java.security.Signature` and normally just do `getInstance` then pass my `PrivateKey` to it, and is able to sign everything no problem. However all the JWT plugins, none of them take the `PrivateKey` like Java do. Which is why I try to wrap it. I did read that post, in fact I even posted a question to ask the author: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/273 however, when I try to implements the interface, I am not sure how to generate the `getEncoded`.

Comment: Oh man, I was running around in circle lol. So it turns out the code I originally wrote was working. I was signing using `Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")`, is just that I was verifying it incorrectly thinking I was doing it wrong, which then lead me to try to use 3rd party JWT libraries to do it... I will post my solution below in case others may be interested in JWT without using 3rd party libraries too.